Question about Smac Planner Lattice Filepath
I have recently started exploring NAV2 Framework for autonomous navigation of a differential driver non-circular robot.
I tested NavFn planner and works okay, but since my robot is non-circular it is better to use smac planner lattice (according to the official documentation).
My question is:
Do I have to create the “lattice_filepath” file by myself or can I just comment out that line and is going to use automatically a pre-exiting file?
I will use the parameters found here: https://docs.nav2.org/configuration/packages/smac/configuring-smac-lattice.html
If I have to create my own, is there a guid to help me do it?
Thank you!

I think you'll need to specify a lattice file because it depends on your robot's motion model and other constraints.
There's information on creating your own lattice file on the navigation2 GitHub page for the nav2_smac_planner: https://github.com/ros-navigation/navigation2/tree/main/nav2_smac_planner/lattice_primitives
There are also samples that you can download on the same GitHub page under nav2_smac_planner/lattice_primitives/sample_primitives.
